# Cookies not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, google-chrome, cookies, localhost

I'm working on an application in localhost:3000 and I just started working with cookies and can't get them to stay saved after I quit out of chrome.  I checked my preferences and they were fine, cookies from other websites like stackoverflow are being retained.  I've tried multiple ways of saving the cookies including

```
cookies.permanent[:guest_user_id] = create_guest_user.id
```

and it's not working (create_guest_user is a method for implementing a guest_user, taken from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user).  Also, Devise isn't saving anything either when I check remember me at the login page.  I even added

```
Devise::TRUE_VALUES << ["on"]
```

as was recommended by another post and that didn't work for me either.  I'm using rails 3.1.1, formtastic 2.0.2, and devise 1.5.1.  I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8 and chrome 15.0.874.121.  Thanks for the help.

UPDATE: I even tried changing my hosts file as was recommended here [Can I use localhost as the domain when setting an HTTP cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489369/can-i-use-localhost-as-the-domain-when-setting-an-http-cookie) and it still isn't working.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there just isn't a relatively easy way of solving this problem in chrome.  I tried out a bunch of solutions from various sources with little success.  Not sure why google has this design in chrome as its developer tools are great and I'm reluctant to switch browsers.